# writing to a txt file in random location java

Tags: java, file-handling, random-access

I am trying to write a string to a txt file at an random location, i.e. i want to edit the specific txt file. I do not want to APPEND, but all i want to do is write some string at, say line 3.
I tried the same using RandomAccessFile, but when I write to a specific line, it replaces the data at that line.

e.g.
a.txt-

1
2
3
4
5

output that is expected by me..

1
2
hi
3
4
5

what i have achieved using RandomAccessFiles

1
2
hi
4
5

---

I tried to save the content of line 3 before replacing, i used readLine() function for that, and its not working, its giving unexpected results.

Comment: i have attached it in the question.. :)

Comment: just want to inform you I've updated my answer considerably since SO last saw you. I think you'll find it interesting.

Answer (score 3):

**For a file that's not too big for memory:**

You could [read the file into a String](https://github.com/kentcdodds/Java-Helper/blob/master/src/com/kentcdodds/javahelper/helpers/IOHelper.java#L65) and then do something like this:

```
String s = "1234567890"; //This is where you'd read the file into a String, but we'll use this for an example.
String randomString = "hi";
char[] chrArry = s.toCharArray(); //get the characters to append to the new string
Random rand = new Random();
int insertSpot = rand.nextInt(chrArry.length + 1); //Get a random spot in the string to insert the random String
//The +1 is to make it so you can append to the end of the string
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
if (insertSpot == chrArry.length) { //Check whether this should just go to the end of the string.
  sb.append(s).append(randomString);
} else {
  for (int j = 0; j < chrArry.length; j++) {
    if (j == insertSpot) {
      sb.append(randomString);
    }
    sb.append(chrArry[j]);
  }
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());//You could then output the string to the file (override it) here.
```

---

**For a file too big for memory:**

You could do some sort of variation of [copying the file](https://github.com/kentcdodds/Java-Helper/blob/master/src/com/kentcdodds/javahelper/helpers/IOHelper.java#L127) where you identify a random spot before-hand and write it in the output stream before the rest of that chunk. Here's some code below:

```
public static void saveInputStream(InputStream inputStream, File outputFile) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
  int size = 4096;
  try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    int length;
    while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
      out.write(buffer, 0, length);
      //Have length = the length of the random string and buffer = new byte[size of string]
      //and call out.write(buffer, 0, length) here once in a random spot.
      //Don't forget to reset the buffer = new byte[size] again before the next iteration.
    }
    inputStream.close();
  }
}
```

Call the above code like this:

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("Your source file.whatever"));
saveInputStream(inputStream, new File("Your output file.whatever"));
```

Comment: i am actually working with a .java file, which is pretty big, around 200+ lines, still will give it a shot, thnkx a lot

Comment: 200+ lines is definitely not too big for memory to handle. You may start getting worried about memory if the file is a gigabyte or two (not sure exactly what point it becomes a problem, depends on your system), so you should be fine :)

Comment: *"200+ lines is definitely not too big for memory to handle."*  AFAIR Java source files had a hard limit of 64Kb.  Easy as pie to read/manipulate/write that amount.

Comment: @AndrewThompson isn't the 64KB limit a byte code limit? You could have much more in the source file, e.g. comments.

Comment: @weston  You might be right there.  It sounds more logical it would be the class size.  Still, I don't think any sensible level of commenting would blow out the size by more than 3x (over no comments).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I regually write GB's of comments :p Yeah I know it's not going to be a problem the OP need worry about.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API to do that.
What you can do is:

1. Choose a random location
2. go to the end of the line
3. Write '\n + 'Your Text'

Comment: @1144031, will try that now. thnks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You only have two options, append and over write. There is no insert method for files as they do not support this operations.  To insert data, you must re-write the rest of the file to move it down.

Comment: i know what u saying, but i am working with .java files here, i want to add an instruction in one of the java file, thats why i cannot afford to over write the data.

Comment: How does that change anything? If you want to insert you have move down the text you want to keep. If you want to delete you have to move up the text so you don't leave a blank. It doesn't matter whether you are writing text or binary, `.java` or `XML` files only work one way.

Comment: alrgiht, it worked.. thnks a lot, stored data from file into temp string, edited it, n wrote it back to file .:) :)